# Weird maven-invoker-plugin exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: Script1 cannot be cast to groovy.lang.GroovyObject

Tags: maven, groovy, maven-invoker-plugin

I am using the `maven-invoker-plugin`. Things were working fine until I started getting the following error (out of nowhere -- there have been no changes to the project itself):

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.094 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-05T14:54:09+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/641M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Running post-build script: /java/jenkins/jobs/project1/jobs/project1-web-integration-tests/workspace/target/it/deploy-and-delete/verify.groovy
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to create Script instance for class: class Script1. Reason: java.lang.ClassCastException: Script1 cannot be cast to groovy.lang.GroovyObject
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:447)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:686)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:568)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:608)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:579)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.scriptinterpreter.GroovyScriptInterpreter.evaluateScript(GroovyScriptInterpreter.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.scriptinterpreter.ScriptRunner.executeRun(ScriptRunner.java:249)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.scriptinterpreter.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:177)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.invoker.AbstractInvokerMojo.runBuild(AbstractInvokerMojo.java:1746)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.invoker.AbstractInvokerMojo.runBuild(AbstractInvokerMojo.java:1415)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.invoker.AbstractInvokerMojo.runBuilds(AbstractInvokerMojo.java:1262)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.invoker.AbstractInvokerMojo.execute(AbstractInvokerMojo.java:737)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven32Launcher.main(Maven32Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:152)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Script1 cannot be cast to groovy.lang.GroovyObject
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:420)
    ... 44 more
```

I have `groovy-all` on the `maven-invoker-plugin`'s `<dependencies/>`. I also tried adding it as a `test`-scoped dependency and I have
`addTestClassPath` : `true`.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

I came across [this post](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Maven-invoker-plugin-addTestClassPath-failing-but-manually-adding-as-dependency-works-td5843422.html), but I don't see an actual solution.

Might be related to [MINVOKER-182](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MINVOKER-182), but I'm not sure...